# Param in js function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-table

I try to get the row id, on expand row.

```
$table.on('expand-row.bs.table', function(e, index, row, $detail) {
    var res = $("#desc" + index).html();
    $detail.html(res);
    var table = document.getElementById("actionTable");
    var row = table.rows[index];
    Cookies.set(row.id, 'show');
    alert(row.id)
});
```

When I try `alert(index)`, the index is shown.

When I try `var row = table.rows[1];`, `alert(row.id)` shows me the id of the row (I have 3 rows in the table)

But when I try with `var row = table.rows[index];`, I am not getting the row id.

I tried with parseInt(), but no success.

Comment: Put, 
```
console.log(table.rows)
console.log(table.rows[index])
```
after `var table = .....`

Comment: @peter can you provide a MCVE???

Comment: Confirm that your `index` value is between 0 and 2 as you have 3 rows and index starts from 0

Comment: @Peter Isn't `row` the row you are looking for? Don't think you even need `table.rows[index]`

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal: yes i can confirm.

Comment: Sure @Peter. I feel that could be the problem for you here. You can comment here exactly what you get on alert or in console.

Comment: @ChrisSatchell: Before it doesn't worked. But after your hint, i tryed again and it works. I had a typo....